# Eigen tensor reshape then broadcast results in gibberish numbers when going from rank 0 to rank 1 tensor

Tags: c++, tensor, eigen3

I have the following code that seeks to find the maximum element of a rank 1 tensor, which shrinks to a rank 0 tensor, and then broadcast it back out to the full length of the rank 1 tensor so I can use it in further computations involving the original rank 1 tensor.

```
//reduces a rank 1 tensor to a rank 0 tensor.
Tensor<double,0> columnmaximum = input_tensor.maximum(this->imposed_dim).eval();

std::cout << "colmax is\n" << columnmaximum << std::endl;

this->columnbroadcast = Eigen::array<int,1> ({M});
this->rank1base = Eigen::array<int,1> ({1});

//expands it back out to a full column. columnshape is just
Tensor<double,1> columnmaximum_rk2 = columnmaximum.reshape(this->rank1base).broadcast(this->columnbroadcast);
std::cout << "colmaxrk2 is\n" << columnmaximum_rk2 << std::endl;
```

and noticed the following strange output:

```
colmax is
-2
colmaxrk2 is
          -2
    0.238402
3.91433e-310
    -3.33086
          -2
```

Something went wrong when broadcasting. My idea was to elevate the rank 0 tensor to a rank 1 tensor (of length one), and then broadcast in the single dimension to replicate the maximum as many times as I need to be able to subtract it from something else.

What is going wrong here with those three numbers in between when printing the enlarged tensor? I know in this special case, I could use the `setConstant` method but would like to use the `reshape` then `broadcast` trick also for higher-dimensional tensors where a summary statistic is less trivial, i.e. a rank 2 tensor etc..

Can anyone explain to me where these non-sensical numbers appear from? Am I committing a basic mistake? The amazingly small number looks a bit like unallocated memory to me.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Using MSVC in debug, an assert is triggered in `std::array::operator[]` called from within Eigen. Putting in an `eval()` seems to work: `Tensor<double, 1> columnmaximum_rk2 = columnmaximum.reshape(rank1base).eval().broadcast(columnbroadcast);`. I am not sure, but it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Sedenion that indeed fixes it! Now, I ran a similar example with a higher order tensor and it's fine. Do you think that may be due to the fact that rank 0 tensors are a bit special?

Comment: I think so that it is related to the rank 0 tensor. At least the [documentation itself](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html#autotoc_md15) has examples of `reshape().broadcast()` without `eval()` in-between for higher rank tensors, so it does not appear to be an unsupported combination of operations. You could [report a bug](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues).

Comment: Also, if you put this as an answer, I shall be happy to mark the question as answered :-) @Sedenion

Comment: Done. While building a minimal example on godbolt, I noticed that Eigen trunk is no longer affected, see my answer. So it is probably not worth to report a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Eigen 3.4.0 related to tensors of dimension zero. Reproducible example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/81zj338ne)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/../unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main()
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> MaxTest(4, 4, 4);
  MaxTest.setRandom();
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 0> columnmaximum = MaxTest.maximum();

  std::cout << "colmax is\n" << columnmaximum << std::endl;

  Eigen::array<Eigen::Index, 1> columnbroadcast({6});
  Eigen::array<Eigen::Index, 1> rank1base({1});

  Eigen::Tensor<double, 1> columnmaximum_rk2 = columnmaximum.reshape(rank1base).broadcast(columnbroadcast);
  std::cout << "colmaxrk2 is\n" << columnmaximum_rk2 << std::endl;
}
```

If the debug checks in the standard library are enabled (`-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` for gcc's stdlibc++), the evaluation of the assignment (`operator=()`) to `columnmaximum_rk2` fails. Without debug, it prints some random values as shown in the original post.

Putting an `eval()` between the `reshape()` and the `broadcast()` prevents the issue ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vfer45Y9h)):

```
Tensor<double, 1> columnmaximum_rk2 = 
  columnmaximum.reshape(rank1base).eval().broadcast(columnbroadcast);
```

Interestingly, Eigen trunk is not affected anymore by the issue ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oP7n1cvGd)). Apparently, it got fixed since Eigen 3.4.0. Indeed, there is [one commit](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/commit/ffb78e23a1b3bc232a07773144cfa5fa1759852d) that at least deals with the tensor broadcast (but I am not sure if this commit specifically fixes the issue).
Thus, another workaround could be to use the current trunk version.